# Beginner's question: \newcommand

Tags: macros

```
\newcommand{\french}[1]{\textbf(#1)}
\french {Voilà notre école.}
\french {(Here’s) our school.}
```

What I get, after running ViewPDF, is:
(Voilà notre école.)
((Here’s) our school.)

What am I doing wrong here? I should be getting bold text, but I get the text between brackets.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The arguments of TeX commands are enclosed within `brackets` (`{}`), not parentheses.

Comment: Braces `{}`, not brackets [] or parens ().

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issue could be solved in comments